# CodeIgniter email class behind proxy server

Tags: codeigniter, email, proxy

Email class in codeigniter is awesome but not if you are behind proxy server. I just make a mechanism to send an email to someone through my reservation application with codeigniter. I test it in my local machine with localhost address and it works. But when i move my code to different machine with some reverse proxy working, it is fail to send. I get some error message as below

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. )

Filename: libraries/myemail.php

Line Number: 29
```

Just remember that i can send the email before, with localhost address. I implement [this](https://github.com/pkandathil/ci_proxy_email) for creating connection through proxy server in my college. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried anything from google links (i.e. searching for that message)? Check first with `phpinfo();` do you have enabled OpenSSL in your PHP configuration. If no, you can check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php) how to install that.

Comment: yeah i have openssl extension enabled..and i already try many things from google links about this..another suggestion?

Comment: Changing ssl to tls with port 587 or 25. Or vice versa if tls is used now.

Comment: ahh i just read some issues about squid..no way using 587 and 25 under squid..i just remember when i successfully sent an email, i connected to vpn server

Comment: Are you developing on xampp? or wamp? you will have to config the email on there if you are? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho and then you can use the codeigniter email library.

Comment: yap, i use xampp and i set all configuration in php.ini...i think i know why i never get this work, my proxy server block 465, 587, and 25..anyway, thanks for the video

Comment: is there any way to send an email with an access to smtp.gmail.com but proxy block ssl connection? my proxy only allow http and https connection